# Clean Build and references

Tags: xcode

This seems pretty straight forward but how do I update a build or maybe whats it called "clean"? Basically sometimes I will move a .H and .M file to a new folder in xcode project navigator. In xcode it shows the files have moved but in Finder the are not moved into the new folder thus in xcode I still have to reference files (like #import "blank") as if it was in the original location even though it shows the files are moved in Xcode. This seems to be the case if I delete files xcode fails cause it is say the file is still there. Does cleaning update the build references??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**xcode groups and the filesystem are not 'connected'**

moves of files in xcode don't affect where files are / need to be on the filesystem and vice versa.

---

what I always do is move files on disk, then REMOVE and READD them in xcode